# Switch to last window

Tags: window, frames

I am trying to use the code from this answer:
[Is there a generic toggle-previous-window function?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7409/is-there-a-generic-toggle-previous-window-function/7411?noredirect=1#comment69062_7411)

```
(defun switch-to-last-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((win (get-mru-window t t t)))
    (unless win (error "Last window not found."))
    (let ((frame (window-frame win)))
      (raise-frame frame)
      (select-frame frame)
      (select-window win))))
```

I had to add: `(select-frame-set-input-focus frame)` to make it work. But with this code or just switching windows using the mouse I have the following problem. Imagine I have two frames, one with one window `f1_w1` and the other with two windows `f2_w1` and `f2_w2`. When I switch from `f1_w1` to `f2_w1` there is no problem, but when on the next cycle after `f2_w1` -> `f1_w1` I switch from `f1_w1` to `f2_w2` I can see the cursor first appear on `f2_w1` and then quickly jump to `f2_w2` making my last visited window `f2_w1` and not `f1_w1` as it should be.

EDIT: as per Drew's comment below that asks for the question. I just find it surprising that Emacs can't properly track the last selected window (unless something is messed up in my configuration). It seems that `get-mru-window` works as expected but switching to a window on another frame seems to be a two step operation under the bonnet, where Emacs selects the previously active window on the target frame (not the one I am switching to) and then quickly jumps to the one I am selecting. Is this behaviour unavoidable when using multiple frames?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: In answer to your revised question "Is this behavior unavoidable when using multiple frames?", "No, it is not unavoidable."  I have been using that snippet verbatim for several months.  I use 4 monitors, two of which each have a separate frame, each with at least two windows at any given time.  I don't doubt that you're experiencing problems.  However, I have not have any of the problems you describe.  Hopefully you can see where this is going... Have you tried replicating the problem with `emacs -Q`?  What are the minimal steps required to reproduce it?  What version of Emacs are you using?

Comment: This post describes how to debug a problem like this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems

Comment: In the end I just went with `ace-window`, it tracks the windows well and it has go to the last window functionality. Works pretty well for me.

Comment: For those wondering, the function from [the `ace-window` package](https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window) which accomplishes this is called `aw-flip-window` (description: Switch to the window you were previously in.). The funcionality of this function is similar to the function `tab-bar-switch-to-recent-tab` defined in `tab-bar.el` but for windows instead of tabs.